# Android DownloadManager not working on smartphone

Tags: android, android-download-manager

Currently I am working on displaying pdf with WebView and trying to implement a download function. I am using download manager to do it. It works on emulator where pdf file is downloaded. However, in smartphone, it just showed 'Download 1 task'. After few second, the notification gone without download anything. I am implement it in Api 19 and above. My smartphone is android 5.1. Is there any solution on this problem?

PdfFullscreenActivity.java

```
public class PdfFullscreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public WebView webview;
public String str;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pdf_fullscreen);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    str = intent.getExtras().getString("PDF_TAG");

    String url = "https://docs.google.com/viewer?embedded=true&url=https://spmsejarahscore.000webhostapp.com/web/media/pdf/" + str;

    webview = (WebView)findViewById(webView);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
    webview.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webview.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize(1024 * 1024);
    webview.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    webview.loadUrl(url);

    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        }

        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return true;
        }
    });
}

public void onBackPressed(){
    super.onBackPressed();
    finish();
}

public void download(View v){
    // https://spmsejarahscore.000webhostapp.com/web/media/pdf/SijilPelajaranMalaysia(SPM)_2011_P1,2.pdf

    String downloadUrl = "https://spmsejarahscore.000webhostapp.com/web/media/pdf/" + str;

    Uri urifile = Uri.parse(downloadUrl);
    downloadfile(urifile, v);
}

public long downloadfile(Uri uri, View view){
    long downloadReference;
    DownloadManager downloadManager;

    // Create request for android download manager
    downloadManager = (DownloadManager)getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);

    //Setting title of request
    request.setTitle("Downloading");

    //Setting description of request
    request.setDescription(str);

    //Set the local destination for the downloaded file to a path within the application's external files directory
    request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(PdfFullscreenActivity.this, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, str);

    //Enqueue download and save into referenceId
    downloadReference = downloadManager.enqueue(request);

    return downloadReference;
}
}
```

activity_pdf_fullscreen.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.foong.spmsejerahscore.PdfFullscreenActivity">

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/downloadbtn"
    android:layout_width="45dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:onClick="download"
    android:background="#264745"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_download" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Not the answer, just a hint: This is **misused**  `android:src="@mipmap/ic_download"` - The `mipmaps` folder/s are meant to contain **only the app laucher icon**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add:

`request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED)`

Comment: Thanks for answering, I have added the code and the pdf is downloaded but it stored in /storage/emulated/0/data/com.example.spmsejarahscore/files/Documents/THE PDF. May I know what can I do to change it to smartphone document directory?

Comment: @Foong `request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/AppName", "file_name.extension");` will save it to your custom directory.

Comment: Thank you very much, this save me a lot